# Listview not working properly c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, listview

I have 2  **ListView** control on my project one of them works perfectly fine, so did the other until recently not sure why its acting very very weird.

Sometime its wont recognized the checked property, sometimes it will sometimes it will return "" when we get the checked property sometime works fine and returns **True** or **False**.

The code to access the ListBox is below, remember i have 2 one works perfectly fine which has same code for getting check status.

ALSO IT started having issue when getting subtext of the middle column always returning "" while others worked so i have to change code to get the desired output from a datatable .

**UPDATE**

**ALSO WHEN I AM IN DEBUGGING MODE AND GO LINE BY LINE IT WORKS FINE EACH TIME AND GETS THE VALUE IF I RUN IT IT WONT GET IT AND SKIPPS ROWS OR MAYBE DOES NOT RECOGNIZE THE CHECKED ROWS !**

```
for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                //  string tmpVal = string.Empty;
                bool tmpVal = false;
                if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    listView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
                        () =>

                        tmpVal = listView1.Items[i].Checked

                            ));
                }
                else
                {
                    tmpVal = listView1.Items[i].Checked;
                }

                if (tmpVal == true)
                {
                    string senderEMail = string.Empty;

                    if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        listView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
                            () =>

                            senderEMail = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.ToString()

                                ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        senderEMail = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();
                    }

                    int rowNumber = 0;

                    string rNumber = string.Empty;


                    if (listView1.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        listView1.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
                            () =>

                            rNumber = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.ToString()

                                ));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rNumber = listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text.ToString();

                    }

                    rowNumber = Convert.ToInt16(rNumber.Trim());

                    if (checkBox2.Checked)
                    {
                        //GET UNSUBSCRUBE URL IF ANY HIT IT AND ALSO SEND EMAIL

                        string unSubscribeUrl = resultSheet.Rows[rowNumber - 1]["UnsubscribeLink"].ToString();
                        string receiver = resultSheet.Rows[rowNumber - 1]["receiver"].ToString();
                        if (unSubscribeUrl != "")
                        {
                            unSubscribeUrl = unSubscribeUrl.Replace("amp;", "").Trim();

                            string html = getHtml(unSubscribeUrl);
                        }

                        //SENDING EMAIL
                        receiver = receiver.ToLower();

                        OutLook.Application oApp1 = new OutLook.Application();
                        OutLook.MailItem mail = oApp1.CreateItem(OutLook.OlItemType.olMailItem) as OutLook.MailItem;

                        mail.Subject = "unsubscribe | uitschrijven | gelieve geen mails te sturen";
                        mail.To = senderEMail;

                        SetAccount_2007_2010(mail, receiver);

                        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(oApp1);
                    }

                    if (checkBox3.Checked)
                    {
                        deleteSenderList.Add(senderEMail);
                    }



                }
            }
```

Comment: You really must have a confused mind if you convert a `bool` to `string` and then compare for `"True"`...

Comment: Yeah maybe had something in my mind at that time :D , but that wont cause the issue would it? also if i debug code it works fine each time,if i run it it wont ...

Comment: It may be because of asynchonous processing caused by calling `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the calls to `BeginInvoke` with calls to `Invoke` - `BeginInvoke` will process asynchronously, which may cause timing issues.